# Kendo UI - Custom Number Formatting Change between 2015.3.1111 -> 2016.1.412

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik

Recently upgraded to Kendo UI version `2016.1.412` from version `2015.3.1111`, and have noticed a fundamental change in the output of Kendo UI custom number formats.  My issue is best shown by example:

```
kendo.toString(245000.45, "#,###;(#,###);-") // returns 245,000 (desired) with v2015.3.1111
kendo.toString(245000.45, "#,###;(#,###);-") // returns 2,45000 with v2016.1.412
```

I've tried various options, some of which come close but still not correct:

```
kendo.toString(245000.45, "#,###.##;(#,###.##);-") // returns 245,000.45, want 245,000
kendo.toString(245000.45, "#,###.00;(#,###.00);-") // returns 245,000.45, want 245,000
```

Online examples :

2015.3.1111 -> http://dojo.telerik.com/efAMi/2

2016.1.412  -> http://dojo.telerik.com/UjiSe/3

Does anyone have any clues as to what I'm either doing wrong, or what's changed? The [online documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberformatting#custom) doesn't give me much to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looks like this is an issue within the kendo 2016.Q1 framework release [this issue](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/1407)

```
kendo.toString(245000.45, "#,###,###,###,###;(#,###,###,###,###);-") // returns 245,000
```